# How to change session data by sessionid in codeigniter using redis library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redis

We have a admin panel built in codeigniter, where two types of user get logged in (admin and super admin). Admin permissions are control by super admin. Admin permissions are stored in session at time of login. We are using codeigniter redis library for storing session data.

Now, the challenge is to update admin user session data without effecting admin login when permissions are changed by super admin.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this on runtime i think with redis it shouldnt be really a problem

Create a pre Controller Hook where you check on every request if users session has been changed

since you use redis - you really don't need to use a DB Query in order to check it - just simply create an object which holds all changed users whose session have been changed and save it to redis

the hook could look like

```
class AppRefreshSession
{
    private $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = get_instance();
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        if (!$this->isSessionValid())
        {
            //refresh users Session
        }
    }

    private function isSessionValid()
    {
        $obj = $this->ci->cache->redis->get("ModifiedSessions_Object");

        if ($obj->hasSessionModified())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;


    }
}
```

And your modified sessions object should get filled with user ids or something like that whenever a superadmin changes the permission.
Save this object to redis and that should pretty much do what you want.